# Applying a function along an axis of a dask array

Tags: python, dask

I'm analyzing ocean temperature data from a climate model simulation where the 4D data arrays (time, depth, latitude, longitude; denoted `dask_array` below) typically have a shape of (6000, 31, 189, 192) and a size of ~25GB (hence my desire to use dask; I've been getting memory errors trying to process these arrays using numpy).

I need to fit a cubic polynomial along the time axis at each level / latitude / longitude point and store the resulting 4 coefficients. I've therefore set `chunksize=(6000, 1, 1, 1)` so I have a separate chunk for each grid point.

This is my function for getting the coefficients of the cubic polynomial (the `time_axis` axis values are a global 1D numpy array defined elsewhere):

```
def my_polyfit(data):    
    return numpy.polyfit(data.squeeze(), time_axis, 3)
```

(So in this case, `numpy.polyfit` returns a list of length 4)

and this is the command I thought I'd need to apply it to each chunk:

```
dask_array.map_blocks(my_polyfit, chunks=(4, 1, 1, 1), drop_axis=0, new_axis=0).compute()
```

Whereby the time axis is now gone (hence `drop_axis=0`) and there's a new coefficient axis in it's place (of length 4).

When I run this command I get `IndexError: tuple index out of range`, so I'm wondering where/how I've misunderstood the use of `map_blocks`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suspect that your experience will be smoother if your function returns an array of the same dimension that it consumes.  E.g. you might consider defining your function as follows:

```
def my_polyfit(data):
    return np.polyfit(data.squeeze(), ...)[:, None, None, None]
```

Then you can probably ignore the `new_axis`, `drop_axis` bits.

Performance-wise you might also want to consider using a larger chunksize.    At 6000 numbers per chunk you have over a million chunks, which means you'll probably spend more time in scheduling than in actual computation.  Generally I shoot for chunks that are a few megabytes in size.  Of course, increasing chunksize would cause your mapped function to become more complex.

### Example

```
In [1]: import dask.array as da

In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: def f(b):
    return np.polyfit(b.squeeze(), np.arange(5), 3)[:, None, None, None]
   ...: 

In [4]: x = da.random.random((5, 3, 3, 3), chunks=(5, 1, 1, 1))

In [5]: x.map_blocks(f, chunks=(4, 1, 1, 1)).compute()
Out[5]: 
array([[[[ -1.29058580e+02,   2.21410738e+02,   1.00721521e+01],
         [ -2.22469851e+02,  -9.14889627e+01,  -2.86405832e+02],
         [  1.40415805e+02,   3.58726232e+02,   6.47166710e+02]],
         ...
```

Comment: I added your suggested `[:, None, None, None]` and tried running `map_blocks` with and without both of `drop_axis=0` and `new_axis=0` but I still get an `IndexError`...

Comment: With respect to the chunksize, if I make it larger I have to introduce looping into my mapped function. That's something I'd really rather avoid, which is why I started playing with dask (i.e. I thought it would be faster). How ridiculous is just over a million chunks? I guess I'm wondering if dask is the most appropriate library for this task, and if not, what might be a more appropriate library? (e.g. should I just be using the multiprocessing library and a simple nested loop over the level, latitude and longitude axes?)

Comment: I've added an example with things working.  There are lots of good options out there; for things like this they're all decent choices.

Comment: Thanks for that example - I've now got it working :-)

Answer (score 7):

Kind of late to the party, but figured this could use an alternative answer based on new features in Dask. In particular, we added [`apply_along_axis`](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/array-api.html?highlight=apply_along_axis#dask.array.apply_along_axis), which behaves basically like [NumPy's `apply_along_axis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html#numpy.apply_along_axis) except for Dask Arrays instead. This results in somewhat simpler syntax. Also it avoids the need to rechunk your data before applying your custom function to each 1-D piece and makes no real requirements of your initial chunking, which it tries to preserve in the end result (excepting the axis that is either reduced or replaced).

```py
In [1]: import dask.array as da

In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: def f(b):
   ...:     return np.polyfit(b, np.arange(len(b)), 3)
   ...: 

In [4]: x = da.random.random((5, 3, 3, 3), chunks=(5, 1, 1, 1))

In [5]: da.apply_along_axis(f, 0, x).compute()
Out[5]: 
array([[[[  2.13570599e+02,   2.28924503e+00,   6.16369231e+01],
         [  4.32000311e+00,   7.01462518e+01,  -1.62215514e+02],
         [  2.89466687e+02,  -1.35522215e+02,   2.86643721e+02]],
         ...
```

Comment: Hi @jakirkham, on what version of dask is `apply_along_axis` available? Version 0.15.2 does not have it

Comment: One needs at least dask 0.15.3.