# Using `dask.array.map_block()` to parallelize line fitting on a 3-D `dask.array`

Tags: python, arrays, dask

I have a series of N images that are recorded at different times. I have stacked the images into a 3-D dask array and rechunked them along the time axis. I would now like to perform a linear fit at each pixel position across the image, but I am running into the following error when using `da.map_blocks` as I try to scale up: `TypeError: expected 1D or 2D array for y`

I found one other post, [applying-a-function-along-an-axis-of-a-dask-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36275052/applying-a-function-along-an-axis-of-a-dask-array), related to this but it didn't address an issue with specifically setting the chunk size. When using `da.apply_along_axis` I found an issue similar to the one reported in [dask-performance-apply-along-axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47314800/dask-performance-apply-along-axis) wherein only one CPU seems to be utilized during the computation (even for chunked data).

MWE: Works properly

```
import dask.array as da
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')

def f(y, args, axis=None):
    return np.polyfit(args[0], y.squeeze(), args[1])[:, None, None]

deg = 1
nsamp=20*10*10
shape=(20,10,10)
chunk_size=(20,1,1)
a = da.linspace(1, nsamp, nsamp).reshape(shape)
chunked = a.rechunk(chunk_size)
times = da.linspace(1, shape[0], shape[0])
results = chunked.map_blocks(f, chunks=(20,1,1), args=[times, deg], dtype='float').compute()
m_fit = results[0]
b_fit = results[1]

# Plot a few fits to visually examine them
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1)
for (x,y) in zip([1,9], [1,9]):
    ax.scatter(times, chunked[:,x,y])
    ax.plot(times, np.polyval([m_fit[x, y], b_fit[x,y]], times))
```

The array, `chunked`, looks like this:

[image]

The resulting plot looks like this,

[image]

Which is exactly what I would expect and so all is well! However, the issue arises whenever I try to use a chunksize larger than one.

MWE: Raises `TypeError`

```
nsamp=20*10*10
shape=(20,10,10)
chunk_size=(20,5,5) # Chunking the data now
a = da.linspace(1,nsamp, nsamp).reshape(shape)
chunked = a.rechunk(chunk_size)
times = da.linspace(1, shape[0], shape[0])
results = chunked.map_blocks(f, chunks=(20,1,1), args=[times, 1], dtype='float') # error
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to what is happening here?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like maybe your function expects single-dimensional inputs.  I wonder if there is a way that you can write a Python function that wraps your function and handles the unpacking and then repacking of one-dimensional inputs.  If you can get that function to work on a single numpy array of shape `(20, 2, 2)` for example then you can probably use Dask to then apply that function across many similarly sized chunks